# Power Shell command to Remove enter / return character in middle of line but leave linefeed as is

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

We have huge csv file ( comma separated enclosed with double quotes).

Some data have enter / return character causing load issues : example below

```
ID,Name,DOB,Gender
"1","John Smith","01-01-1980","M"
"2","Craig 
Davis","02-02-1990","M"
"3","David Smith","05-05-1970","M"
```

I tried to fix this issue by command :

```
((Get-Content -path C:\Users\10145097\work\RnD\sample_data.txt -Raw) -replace "`n|`r","")
```

but it removed line separator also, which we don't want :

Incorrect output

```
ID,Name,DOB,Gender"1","John Smith","01-01-1980","M""2","Craig Davis","02-02-1990","M""3","David Smith","05-05-1970","M"
```

The required output is :

```
ID,Name,DOB,Gender
"1","John Smith","01-01-1980","M"
"2","Craig Davis","02-02-1990","M"
"3","David Smith","05-05-1970","M"
```

Could you please help in this.

Many Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
rem The following settings for the source directory, destination directory, target directory,
rem batch directory, filenames, output filename and temporary filename [if shown] are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include names which include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "destdir=u:\your results"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q65605302.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"

SET "line="
SET "unbalanced="

(
 FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
  IF DEFINED unbalanced (ECHO !line!%%a&SET "unbalanced=") ELSE (
   SET "line=%%a"
   CALL :countquotes
   IF DEFINED unbalanced (SET "line=%%a") ELSE ECHO %%a
  )
)
)>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF

:countquotes
IF NOT DEFINED line GOTO :EOF
SET "char=%line:~0,1%"
SET "line=%line:~1%"
SET "char=%char:"=%"
IF DEFINED char GOTO countquotes
IF DEFINED unbalanced (SET "unbalanced=") ELSE SET "unbalanced=y"
GOTO countquotes
```

Personally, I'd use `sed` or `(g)awk` to attempt to repair your file.

Without actually being able to analyse the raw source data, I can only conclude from the posted data that the problem is that a newline is being inserted at random after the space in a quoted field.

This batch simply reads the file, line-by-line.

If the flag `unbalanced` is set, then the previous line was unbalanced, so append the current `%%a` to the previous line saved in `line` and output, then set `unbalanced` as false (no value).

If `unbalanced is not set`, then "count" the number of quotes on the current line. The "counting" is accomplished by simply frobbing the `unbalanced` flag, so if there is an odd number of double-quotes, `unbalanced` will be `set`; if an even number then it will be clear.

On return from the `:countquotes` routine, regurgitate the line if `unbalanced` is not set (ie. the line read had balanced quotes), otherwise save the line again in `line` (as `:countquotes` has destroyed it) ready to be concatenated to the next line read.

Comment: Hi Magoo, Thanks for your response. 2 things, there are up-to 5-10 fields and file contains 3.5 Million records. So we had to request source team (SQL server) to replace CHR(10) and CHR(13) while generating file. Appreciated your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

If you have enough memory to load/parse the file, you can use the below approach to clear the newlines:

```
$data = Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\TheFile.csv'
foreach ($item in $data) {
    # replace all fields that contain Newline characters
    foreach ($prop in ($item.PSObject.Properties.Name | Where-Object { $item.$_ -match '\r?\n'})) {
        # remove the Newline characters:
        $item.$prop = $item.$prop -replace '[\r\n]'

        # OR
        # to normalize all multiple whitespace characters into a single space use:
        # $item.$prop = $item.$prop -replace '\s+', ' '
    }
}

$data | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\TheUpdatedFile.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

If you can be certain the newlines only appear in column `Name`, you can simplify the above code to:

```
$data = Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\TheFile.csv'
foreach ($item in $data) {
    # replace all fields in column 'Name' that contain Newline characters
    if ($item.Name -match '\r?\n') {
        # remove the Newline characters:
        $item.Name = $item.Name -replace '[\r\n]'

        # OR
        # to normalize all multiple whitespace characters into a single space use:
        # $item.Name = $item.Name -replace '\s+', ' '
    }
}

$data | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\TheUpdatedFile.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Using your example, the CSV output looks like

```
"ID","Name","DOB","Gender"
"1","John Smith","01-01-1980","M"
"2","Craig Davis","02-02-1990","M"
"3","David Smith","05-05-1970","M"
```

Comment: Hi Theo, Thanks for your response. 2 things, there are up-to 5-10 fields and file contains 3.5 Million records. So we had to request source team (SQL server) to replace CHR(10) and CHR(13) while generating file. Appreciated your inputs.

Comment: @Sourabh if I understand correctly, you would need the first approach, but with a file that large, you will also need a machine with loads of memory and it will take its time to complete..